# python3 TypeError: '<' not supported error when try to implement A* algo use python heapq

Tags: python, python-3.x, priority-queue, a-star

I am trying to implement A* algorithm using pri_que by leveraging python library *heapq*. In general, all the state of will be stored as a **Node** instance

```
class Node:
   def __init__(self, state, parent, action, depth):
        self.path_cost = 0
        self.state = state
        self.parent = parent
        self.action = action
        self.depth = depth
```

The code is too long to paste here, but the error locates in the following block.

```
    def astar_insert(self, node):
        hq.heappush(self.pri_que, (node.path_cost, node))
        self.visited_pri.add(str(node.state))
    
 
    def astar_pop(self):
        
        node = hq.heappop(self.pri_que)[1] # <-------------------- this line

        self.visited_pri.discard(str(node.state))
        return node
```

The full error is:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Node' and 'Node'
```

I am very confused. I try to run the code and print the solution. It seems like the code works for a well before failing.

Comment: Can you provide the full definition of `Node`? How do you expect two `Node` instances to be compared?

Comment: @Brian61354270 Just revise the post. The Node is defined above. I honestly didn't make any comparison between two nodes. Which is why I am so confused.

Comment: For example, in my code, I only use node.state without making any operations such as <, ==, or >

Comment: You make comparisons between `Nodes` by putting them into a heap queue. That's how the heap algorithm works. If you can't compare `Nodes`, they can't be used in a heap

Comment: @Brian61354270: They can be used in a heap if you guarantee that the comparison of the `tuple`s will never fall back to comparing the `Node` instances. But comparing on costs alone is highly unlikely to achieve that (and clearly didn't, in the OP's case).

Answer (score 2):

The crux of your problem is:

1. Your `path_cost`s aren't unique (meaning entries in the heap must fall back to comparing the `Node`s themselves), and
2. Your `Node` class doesn't define a comparison for less-than (causing the `TypeError` for incomparable types).

There are two possible solutions:

1. Push stuff on the heap with a guaranteed unique comparable value between the cost and the `node` itself. A good source of such guaranteed unique comparable values would be [an instance of `itertools.count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count). Once you've made one, you'd call `hq.heappush(self.pri_que, (node.path_cost, next(counter), node))` for the insertion, ensuring the `node` instance would never be compared.
2. Make your `Node`s comparable by defining `__lt__` on the class with some meaningful comparison. You'd also want to define `__eq__` and use the `@functools.total_ordering` decorator to ensure it's comparable for all purposes (not just the `__lt__` that Python uses for ordering comparisons in the built-ins, but for other purposes where `>` or `<=` or `>=` are used).

Comment: I find the issue. Turns out you guys are right. ```__lt__`` solve the problem

Comment: I think what heappush does is if the first element in the tuple is the same, it will compare the second element

Comment: @Rieder: It's not `heappush` doing it at all. That's how *all* `tuple` comparisons work. It's called lexicographic ordering; the heap utilities are type-agnostic, they just ask whether the "instance" (in this case, a 2-tuple) is less than the other instance. `tuple` itself is checking left-to-right until it finds an unequal element, then basing the overall result on the result of comparing the unequal elements. That's why solution #1 works; even when costs are tied, by ensuring the *second* comparison is always unequal, the `tuple` comparison never compares the (non-comparable) third elements.